NextJS App router: Generate static subdomains, and access it in page file
I'm using NextJS 14, with App router.
We are having a multi-tenancy website, so we have dynamic subdomains.
We are having output: 'export' inside the next.config.js file, which means that no dynamic content is allowed. Next immediately gives error if I do something dynamic, like access headers from next/headers in a server component, which can be used to access the hostname. I'm not allowed to change the next config file for dynamic rendering.
Reason I want to access the subdomain inside a page.tsx file (a server component), is because I'm making an API call there, and I need to pass subdomain inside header, like so
async function getData(subdomain: string) {
    const res = await fetch('our_backend_api', {
        headers: {
            subdomain: subdomain
        }
    })
    return res.json();
}

export default async function Home() {
    // I need some code here to access subdomain
    const homeData = await getData(subdomain)

    return (
        <SomeComponent data={homeData} />
    )
}

I have also explored the option of using middleware, but it again does not work with the static export configuration. I've tried using it as well, where I was trying to use the request parameter to access the hostname like so
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const hostname = request.nextUrl.hostname; // Extract subdomain from the hostname
    const url = request.nextUrl.clone();
    
    // Add subdomain as a search parameter
    url.searchParams.set('subdomain', hostname);

    // Forward the modified request
    return NextResponse.rewrite(url);
}

Next throws an error saying that middleware cannot be used with output: 'export' option, something along those lines
I was expecting something similar to generateStaticParams, where I can return an array of subdomains by fetching them first in it, but sadly that works only for dynamic routes, not hosts.
Doing this on the client side is not an option, as SEO is very important for us.
I would prefer to solve this from frontend itself, as I'm a frontend guy, but architecture related answers are also welcome :)
